# Grid with freezon last column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I have to create a angular grid with last column frozen. The frozen column is the summation of all the row values. The last row is an editable one. My problem is how to create the HTML/CSS structure. I can create the angular grid but how to create the HTML/CSS structure is my question. Attached is the screen shot of the grid required.

Any pointers very helpful.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Just think two div columns each with it's own table. One div has `overflow-y:scroll` and lots of columns in table , the other table only has one column

Comment: did some quick thing - Just wanted to check if this could be a solution :http://jsfiddle.net/anirbankundu/DJqPf/1875/

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the great suggestion - It works ! I will post my answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with : http://jsfiddle.net/anirbankundu/DJqPf/1881/

I implemented using 2 ways - I have indicated in the fiddle which is a more favorable way to implement. Hope that helps
HTML :

```
    <div id="left">
      <h4>Left Col</h4>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="text-align:right;">
      <h4>Right Col</h4>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width: 250px;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

th:first-child {
  position: fixed;
  right: 35%
}

#container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#row {
  display: table-row;
}

#left,
#right,
#middle {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#left {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```